# div does not show up

Tags: html, css

I put a couple of divs in the same manner and all worked fine, except this one

```
  .recommend{
    color:#F0F0F0;
    left:66px;
    border-radius:1em;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    top: 140px;
}
```

and this is the div in the body,

```
 <body>
    <div class="recommend"></div>
 </body>
```

It does not show up at all when viewed in browser.

this is the whole script if something is interfering and I am unable to see

```
<style>
.aside{
  position: fixed;
  right: 66px;
  top:0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 108px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.nav{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius:1em;
    right: 200px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
 .bigheader {
   font-family: Calibri;
   color: #FFF;
   position:fixed;
   top: 64px;
   left: 66px;  
}
.header{
        font-size:56px;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.header1{
        color:#FFF;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:Calibri;
}
.textnav{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    position:fixed;
}
.recommend{
    color:#F0F0F0;
    left:66px;
    border-radius:1em;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    top: 140px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body> 
   <div class="aside"><a href="some link" width="30" height="30" /></a>   </div>
   <div class="nav">
     <span class="textnav">Archive</span></div>
   <div class="bigheader">
      <span class="header">Some text</span>
      <br />
      <span class="header1">some more text</span></div>
      <div class="recommend"></div>
      <div class="body"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am new to css, corrected "color" to "background-color" now I see a big block (which I wanted).
Any suggestions on how to layout would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

You were missing content and you did not specify a background-color so your div was not visible, blending in with the default body colour.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Recommend Div </title>
    <style>
    .recommend{
        background-color:#000;
        color:#FFF;
        left:66px;
        border-radius:1em;
        width:600px;
        height:400px;
        top: 140px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="recommend">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added background,

      html { 
  background:url(images/1bg-bed.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

Still does not show up

Comment: just copy my code, save it in to a file, and run it, it is working fine on my end, no need for backgrund url's etc just a background-color to identify the container on the page

Comment: You should also not be using all that fixed positioning, just use relative or absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

It does not show up because all you have is a div with no content inside of it.

A div is just a **container** where you can add HTML elements such as **input** tags or **textarea** tags. This way elements can be grouped together and then styles can be applied to these div sections.

Your *footer* and *body* tags would also not 'show up' as they are just now because they are also just divs with no other HTML elements inside.

Comment: I know that footers and other divs that have no css style does not show up as long as I dont have a style to it. But there should be a box when i code.
Also, when added text to that certain div, it just shows on the background plainly as if nothing supports it

Comment: if you want a box then add the corresponding element/tags within the div with class 'recommend'. that would be the correct way

Answer (score 2):

Divs are never visible. They are a semantic element used to encapsulate HTML elements. You will never see a div, think of it as an invisible line which separates content on your page.

Answer (score 1):

The div is there on the page, however you have two problems.

The first is that you have no content in the recommend div and secondly your style is set to display the colour as white, and you have a white background. Simply remove the `color` property.

**Add the content:**

```
<div class="recommend">recommend section</div>
```

**Adjust the style to remove the white colour property:**

```
.recommend{
    left:66px;
    border-radius:1em;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    top: 140px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/he7djuuo/

Answer (score 0):

The div does not contain any content so there is nothing to show. Give the CSS class a backgroud-color and you will probably see the div.

Answer (score 0):

background-color CSS was the missing component.
Any block element can be positioned, sized, and styled with color and it will be visible.  The div tags could easily be replaced by p tags and it would still behave the same way. Just to reiterate, a size (defined width and height) and color is all that is needed for a block element; the content is not necessary (it can be blank and will show up as a blank colored rectangle).